# ForeignKey error in ormar has no attribute 'get_column_alias'

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, alembic, ormar

I'm testing out ormar to avoid having to create models for both api and database and ran into an issue with foreignkey assignment I can't seem to figure out.

The base code works before I deleted the database and try to recreate again with the new foreignkey.

```
import databases
import ormar
import sqlalchemy
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

database = databases.Database("sqlite:///db.sqlite")
# database = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()


class BaseMeta(ormar.ModelMeta):
    database = database
    metadata = metadata


class TaskTypes(ormar.ModelMeta):
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        tablename = "tasktypes"

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=64)


class Tasks(ormar.ModelMeta):
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        tablename = "tasks"

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    title: str = ormar.String(max_length=64)
    tasktypes: Optional[TaskTypes] = ormar.ForeignKey(TaskTypes)
```

the error is

```
File "/Repositories/MVP/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ormar/fields/foreign_key.py", line 114, in populate_fk_params_based_on_to_model

fk_string = to.Meta.tablename + "." + to.get_column_alias(to.Meta.pkname)

AttributeError: type object 'TaskTypes' has no attribute 'get_column_alias'
```

Any help would be great.   Thanks

Comment: This is the command I'm running from the terminal 

"alembic revision --autogenerate -m "DB created core tables created"

Answer (score 2):

Your models must inherit from `ormar.Model` and not `ModelMeta`.

So the valid code is:

```py
import databases
import ormar
import sqlalchemy
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

database = databases.Database("sqlite:///db.sqlite")
# database = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()


class BaseMeta(ormar.ModelMeta):
    database = database
    metadata = metadata


class TaskTypes(ormar.Model): # change here
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        tablename = "tasktypes"

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=64)


class Tasks(ormar.Model): # change here
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        tablename = "tasks"

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    title: str = ormar.String(max_length=64)
    tasktypes: Optional[TaskTypes] = ormar.ForeignKey(TaskTypes)
```